# SIDH: key agreement - why does it work?

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

In SIDH both parties agree on the key in following way:

1. Alice calculates a kernel $R = mPB + nQB$
2. Thanks to Velu formulas (and further improvements), she can now compute isogeny $\phi_a$
3. She uses $\phi_a$ to start hers random walk and ends up with trio $(E_a, \phi_a(PB),\phi_a(PB))$
4. Now she sends this trio to Bob (I know, she actually sends 3 points)
5. Bob does the same, let say his secret isogeny is $\phi_b$. Upon receipt of corresponding trio from Bob $(E_b, \phi_b(PA), \phi_b(QA))$ Alice uses $m, n$ to compute new kernel $R' = m*\phi_b(PA) + n*\phi_b(QA)$ and new isogeny
6. Then she starts from $E_b$ and does the random walk again ending on $E_{ab}$
7. Bob proceeds *mutatis mutandis* and ends up on a probably different curve $E_{ba}$, but surely in same isomorphism class as Alice. Thanks to j-invariant then can agree on a shared secret $j(E_{ab}) == j(E_{ba})$

Now, I've to say point 6. and 7. are a bit black magic to me. I understand that we have this equality here:

$R' =m*\phi_b(PA) + n*\phi_b(QA) = \phi_b(m*PA + n*QA)$

But still, why exactly they will end up in the same isomorphism class? What is a mathematical base, for those two isogenies to converge to the same class. I'm wondering how would a proof look like for this.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "isogeny class" and "isomorphism class". That two isogenous curves are in the same isogeny class is a tautology. Your question is about why E_ab and E_ba are in the same *isomorphism* class.

Comment: Argh, obviously it should say isomorphism class. Fixed now

Answer (score 4):

I invented SIDH and can surely answer any technical questions about it. Proofs of $E_{ab} \cong E_{ba}$ are given in several places, though rarely in official Theorem / Proof form, because this result is just an application of well-established theory on elliptic curves rather than any sort of new mathematical result that merits formal statement as a theorem. See for example the [original paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506) (Section 3.2, in particular the (unique) displayed equation in that section), or [De Feo's survey article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04062) (page 34), or [Martindale and Panny's cryptanalysis summary](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/558) (page 4, paragraph "Key exchange").

If you have a more specific question, please ask away.